# Gnome not starting in FreeBSD

Tags: gnome, freebsd

I tried to install gnome2 in FreeBSD using the command `pkg_add -v -r gnome2`. I also edited my file in `/etc/rc.conf` and added the lines `gdm_enable="YES"` and `gnome_enable="YES"` and also added the lines in `/etc/fstab`  `proc           /proc       procfs  rw  0   0` . Still I typed startx in my prompt it gave me error for command not found. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use `gdm`, you don't need `startx` (if you really want it, you need to install the `x11/xinit` port to get it). `gdm` is a graphical login manager, whereas `startx` is used to begin an X session from the command line.

Although you have edited your system configuration files as instructed, you now need to either reboot the system so that the normal startup process can mount the `procfs` file system and start up all the services that GNOME requires, or you can do it by hand:

```
sudo mount -at procfs
sudo service dbus start
sudo service avahi-daemon start
sudo service avahi-dnsconfd start
sudo service hald start
sudo service gdm start
```

(The presence of `gnome_enable` in your `/etc/rc.conf` file causes these services to be run automatically at startup.)

Comment: I have gdm installed so that means I dont have to now install x11/xinit right?

Comment: while starting gdm it gives a warning stating "WARNING **: Failed to acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager" and "WARNING **: Could not acquire name; bail out" also "host name not found: 2.freebsd.pool.ntp.org" any help?

Comment: Is name resolution working correctly on your system? Is the machine properly connected to the Internet? On the command line, try `host 2.freebsd.pool.ntp.org` and see what you get. And no, you don't need to install `xinit` if you want to use `gdm`

Comment: No my machine is not connected to the internet. can that be the problem causing it?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is causing the DNS failure. Is connecting this machine an option?

Comment: yes there is I will give it a try again and let you know if that solves my gnome problem because other things seems fine to me.